# #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 3

Tags: mysql, jsp

Me sale error en la linea numero 3 (declare nro int) es un prodecimiento de SQL para JSP.
**codigo**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPFACTURA(in codc char(8),in tot numeric(8,1))
BEGIN
declare nro int;
declare fac char(8);
select ifnull(max(nrofactura),0) + 1  from faccab into nro;
set fac = lpad(nro,8,'0');
insert into faccab values (fac,current_date(),codc,tot);
select fac;
END@@
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor dale clic en [edit] la pregunta y añade el mensaje de error exacto que obtienes. Un saludo.